# Event found in tail sigma field

Tags: measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $S_n = \sum_{i =1}^n X_i $. Then the event $[\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n} = 0]$ is an event found in the tail sigma algebra generated by the $\{X_n\}$.

The proof is straightforward I believe : the trick is to realize that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n < \infty$ iff $\sum_{n=m}^\infty X_n < \infty$. Therefore, the event

$$ [\lim_{n \to \infty}S_n/n = 0] \text{ is equivalent to } [\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sum_{i =m}^n X_i)/n = 0] \text{ for any fixed }m$$

and the result holds.

**Question:** Is it possible to extend this result to another limit (other than zero) ? For example, if the $\{X_n\}$ are i.i.d then by SLLN we know that the sample average converges to $\mu$. In this case, would the event $[\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n/n = \mu]$ also be measurable wrt to the tail sigma field?

Comment: The statement you wish to prove is true, but I'm not following the trick you've presented. How does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n < \infty$ iff $\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} X_n < \infty$ imply that $\{\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n/n =0\}$ is equivalent to $\{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=m}^n X_i / n = 0\}$?

Comment: What I meant was the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ converges iff it's tail converges. Therefore, the set $B= \{ \omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) /n = 0 \}$ should be equivalent to the set $\{ \omega \in \Omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{i=m}^n X_i)/n = 0 \}$. For each $m$, the sequence $X_1(\omega),...,X_{m-1}(\omega)$ does not affect the question whether or not $\omega \in B$

Comment: What is the connection between $\sum X_n$ converging and this question?  You need to explain your "iff it's tail converges. Therefore, the set $B = [\ldots]$" step.  You don't need to explain what the individual statements mean.  You need to explain how one implies the other (the "therefore"), because at the moment you have two arguably true statements, but no connection between the two.  (E.g. "One plus one equals two.  Therefore a triangle has three sides")

Answer (score 1):

As long as the $X_n$ are surely finite, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_m/n = 0$, for any fixed $m$.

Therefore, under the same assumption, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n/n = \lim_{n\to\infty}(S_n-S_m)/n$$

Since for $n > m$, $S_n-S_m \in \sigma(X_k : k > m)$, we can see $$\{\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n/n = \mu\} = \{\lim_{n\to\infty}(S_n-S_m)/n = \mu\} \in \sigma(X_k : k > m)$$ for all $m$, so $\{\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n/n = \mu\}$ is in the tail $\sigma$-field.